# Альтернатива DateInterval("P1D")

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$interval = new DateInterval( "P1D" );
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    foreach($daterange as $date){
        $startDateNew = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        echo $startDateNew.'</br>';
    }
```

В локальной версии Денвера все работает, а на сервере Sweb.ru с версией PHP5: 5.2.5 (mod) не хочет работать.

Подскажите как обойти DateInterval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateInterval` доступен для `PHP 5 >= 5.3.0`

Для его включения попробуйте тут почитать: `http://help.sweb.ru/entry/3951/`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.